# How to install pods (based on pod name) to specific nodes in K8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I understand that the nodeSelector will help to move the pods to specific nodes with labels. But, say if I know the names for pods in advance and based on these names, how do I move these pods to different nodes having specific labels.
I am unable to understand as to how to use nodeSelector, affinity, antiAffinity in this case.
What would an example values.yaml look like?

I have labelled three nodes. Then, when I launch the 6 pods, they are equally divided among the nodes. Each pod has an index value at the end of the pod name. mypod-0, mypod-1 until mypod-5.

I want to have mypod-0 and mypod-3 on node 1, mypod-1 and mypod-4 on node 2 and so on.

Comment: Why do you want such a specific placement?  If you're merely worried about resource contention between the pods, can you use resource constraints to ensure each has enough memory and CPU, and let the cluster figure out an appropriate placement?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need to measure performance with different configurations of pods by placing them manually on each node and finding the most acceptable performing configuration. The nodes will be of bare metal type.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Pod Topology Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) to decide how the pods need to spread across your **cluster**.

For Example as per you question we can deploy **2 pods in 1 node** and other **2 pods in different node**. To make this possible we need to set the `topologyKey` for nodes and use them while deploying the pod. This sample yaml shows the syntax of pod topology constraints.

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: zone
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        foo: bar
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
```

Since you are using labels for naming the pods you can use nodeAffinity and nodeSelectors along with pod topology constraints. For more information regarding the combination of topology and affinity refer to this [official k8 document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#interaction-with-node-affinity-and-node-selectors)

Comment: I will check this out and revert back. Thanks!